# scala spark reduce list in groupby

Tags: list, scala, apache-spark, reduce

I have spark DataFrame with two columns

```
colA colB
1    3
1    2
2    4
2    5
2    1
```

I want to groupBy colA and iterate over colB list for each group such that:

```
res = 0
for i in collect_list(col("colB")):
    res += i * (3+res)
```

returned value shall be res

so I get:

```
colA colB
1    24
2    78
```

how can i do this in scala?

Comment: Use `reduceByKey`

Comment: thank you for pointint me into direction. would be be so kind to provide me with a minimum working example for e.g. List(8,4) ? thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the result you want with the following:

```
val df = Seq((1,3), (1,2), (2,4), (2,5), (2,1)).toDF("colA", "colB")
val retDf = df
  .groupBy("colA")
  .agg(
    aggregate(
      collect_list("colB"), lit(0), (acc, nxt) => nxt * (acc + 3)
    ) as "colB")
```

You need to be very careful with this however, as data on Spark is distributed. If the data has been shuffled since being read into Spark there is no guarantee that it will be collected in the same order. In the toy example `collect_list("colB")` will return `Seq(3,2)` where `colA` is `1`. If there had been any shuffles at an earlier phase however, `collect_list` can just as well return `Seq(2,3)` which would give you `27` instead of the desired `24`. You need to provide some metadata to your data which you can use to ensure you're processing this in the order you expect such as with the `monotonicallyIncreasingId` method.

Comment: Per your own admission the answer is not correct.

Comment: How so? It solves the question asked. I don't know the context the solution is being used in so I provided the necessary caveat and indicated how to solve that problem should it apply.

Comment: Look st your reservations...indeterminate...

Answer (score 0):

RDD approach with no loss of ordering.

```
%scala
val rdd1 = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq((1,3), (1,3), (2,4), (2,5), (2,1))).zipWithIndex().map(x => ((x._1._1), (x._1._2, x._2)) )
val rdd2 = rdd1.groupByKey
// Convert to Array.
val rdd3 = rdd2.map(x => (x._1, x._2.toArray)) 
val rdd4 = rdd3.map(x => (x._1, x._2.sortBy(_._2)))
val rdd5 = rdd4.mapValues(v => v.map(_._1))
rdd5.collect()

val res = rdd5.map(x => (x._1, x._2.fold(0)((acc, nxt) => nxt * (acc + 3) )))
res.collect()
```

returns:

```
res201: Array[(Int, Int)] = Array((1,24), (2,78))
```

Covert from and to DF as required.

Comment: Something odd about it.

Comment: I am wondering if the formula is correct, I think the 1st value should be 33 due to res +=

Comment: Would need + acc added. foldLeft als possible.